# Using JavaScript in Polymer element

Tags: javascript, jquery, polymer

I have an object of polymer:

```
<newfolder-element id="newfolderelement" popupStyle="width: 362px; height: 100px;">
    <span class="title">Utwórz nowy folder</span>
    <input type="text" class="ginput" style="width: 350px; padding: 5px;" placeholder="Nowy katalog" />
    <br />
    <button class="action blue"><span class="label">Utwórz</span></button>
    <button class="action red" id="cancelBtn"><span class="label">Anuluj</span></button>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            ...
        </script>

</newfolder-element>
```

I want to access dom elements in javascript, I tried this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

                    Polymer('newfolderelement', {
                        domReady : function(){
                            $(this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#cancelBtn")).on('click', '#cancelBtn', function(){
                                console.log("clicked");
                            });
                        }
                    });
</script>
```

And this:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
                    $(this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#cancelBtn")).on('click', '#cancelBtn', function(){
                        console.log("clicked");
                    });

</script>
```

And this:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
                    $("#cancelBtn").click(function(){
                        console.log("clicked");
                    });

</script>
```

But all of above doesn't work. How to access dom elements inside polymer object ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want to use jQuery, the Polymer already provides that functionality to you:

- to access DOM elements use the [`$` map](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/creatingelements.html#automatic-node-finding) of the element, ie to get reference to the `#cancelBtn` use

  this.$.cancelBtn
- to add an eventhandler use [declarative event mapping](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#declarative-event-mapping), ie to add an click handler to the button

```
<button class="action red" id="cancelBtn" on-click="{{cancelClicked}}"></button>
```

and just add method `cancelClicked` to your component's script section.

```
  <script>
    Polymer('newfolder-element', {
      cancelClicked: function() {
         // do something
      }
    });
  </script>
```

This is much simpler and your component won't require additional library.

Comment: That's doesn't work. Notice that, I don't want to use JS in component but object of component.

Comment: Oh, got wrong impression of what you want... but the point of web components is that the internals of the component wont "leak" into document, so what you want is kind of against the idea of web components... if the component's public API doesn't support what you want then perhaps redesign it so that you don't need to "hack" it's internals.

Comment: You're right, I think. I wanted to make base component "popup" with basic functions and UI (close button etc) and inherit it with variety of popups in my app (creation of new folder, upload files etc) so, maybe polymer is not good way to do this because every popup will be completely different from another.